# I am making a python web app. Need help understanding how to host, format. present it

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, database, web-applications

**Hello**! I am working on a project, a web app that takes homework from users and presents them. For example One student enters **Maths HW: Q1-5**, after his school puts the due date and subject accordingly. then later when he goes back to the web app, he sees all his homework arranged in a table, whether an excel sheet or a database. how do I achieve this> As I said I want it to be a web app. So should I host this and use flask or repl.it or what?????? Please help

Answer (score 2):

Great Question. First in python I suggest using flask as a framework. For hosting replit.com will do the trick but without their paid subscription it won't be up 24/7. If you want to host, a good idea for beginners is pythonanywhere. There are many tutorials on youtube like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jbdkOlf4cY&t=220s). For further production I would suggest platforms like Heroku.